# How Compiler Explorer (godbolt) runs the code safely?

Tags: c++, clang, compiler-explorer

What I want to achieve:
Players can share C++ source code, build in their machines as plugins, and run those plugins. However, how can I prevent malicious source code?

How CompileExplorer or other online compilers approach this? VM? docker? Downgrading privileges?

Maybe modifying clang? but where to start?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: He gave a talk at CppCon not long ago that went over this, if I recall correctly he basically put the execution within Docker containers. [Here](https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues/429) was the pull request with more details.

Comment: Have a read of - https://xania.org/201609/how-compiler-explorer-runs-on-amazon   _"...The Docker container is even more restricted than the EC2 instance it runs in: should someone find a remote exploit then at best they can fiddle with the contents of that (ephemeral) container and not actually do any lasting damage...."_

Comment: as far I see in this thread: https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues/429, they are using FireJail, but it's only for Linux

Answer (score 0):

As of today (2023) CE doesn't use containers, and I think around 2019 they moved from FireJail to [nsjail](https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/blob/271d5ff788862cd4a30a6e68cd29a43b83d15a54/etc/config/execution.amazon.properties#L1). There's also still [some legacy code](https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/blob/271d5ff788862cd4a30a6e68cd29a43b83d15a54/lib/compilation-env.ts#L174) that prevents running with switches that were once considered unsafe (eg clang plugins).